# Add current date and time to DatePicker

Tags: razor, datetimepicker, asp.net-core-2.2

How can you bind the current date and time to a datetimepicker in ASP.NET Core 2.2.

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Issue date and time :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input asp-for="DateTimeValue" class="form-control" required />
    </div>
</div>

public DateTime DateTimeValue { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `value` attribute to the current date for the default value:

```
<input asp-for="DateTimeValue" value="@DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm tt")" 
     class="form-control" required />
```

And then get rid of the `= DateTime.Now` from your get-set object.